# Template instantiation warning using std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, visual-c++, std, unordered-map

I've got a type `IVector3` provided by the glm library:

```
using IVector3 = glm::ivec3;
```

I've got a hash function for IVector3s:

```
struct IVector3Hash
{
    std::size_t operator()(IVector3 const& i) const noexcept
    {
        std::size_t seed = 0;
        boost::hash_combine(seed, i.x);
        boost::hash_combine(seed, i.y);
        boost::hash_combine(seed, i.z);
        return seed;
    }
};
```

And I'm trying to map IVector3s to floats in an unordered_map:

```
std::unordered_map<IVector3, float, IVector3Hash> g_score;
```

However, when I try and emplace a value in this map, I get a warning that I need to see the reference to function template instantiation:

```
g_score.emplace(from_node->index, 0);

1>c:\users\accou\documents\pathfindingexamples\c++ library\pathfindinglib\pathfindinglib\pathfinding.cpp(44): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>,boo 
l> std::_Hash<std::_Umap_traits<_Kty,float,std::_Uhash_compare<_Kty,_Hasher,_Keyeq>,_Alloc,false>>::emplace<IVector3&,int>(IVector3 &,int &&)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::pair<const IVector3,float>,
1>            _Kty=IVector3,
1>            _Hasher=IVector3Hash,
1>            _Keyeq=std::equal_to<IVector3>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const IVector3,float>>
1>        ]
```

I've looked through the documentation for std::pair and std::unordered_map but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. The code compiles, but I don't want errors to occur if other compilers are used.

Thank you for any help :)

EDIT to include full warning text: https://pastebin.com/G1EdxKKe

Comment: Please copy-paste full warning text. What you provided is only a part of it.

Comment: when you emplace use `0.0f`, not `0`; because 0 is an int not a float

Comment: Aha let me try that real quick

Comment: Thank you @Raxvan that solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was confused by the long-winded error output, but the actual error was because I was trying to [`emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace)(...) using an int rather than a float as the map required.

Changing to:

```
g_score.emplace(from_node->index, 0.0f);
```

solved the issue.